# C: Unable to exit program with multiple inputs

Tags: c

This code is supposed to exit when I type in EXIT, but when I type EXIT nothing happens, anything I input after it exits the program.  Can someone point out what's wrong? Although it works fine when I don't scan multiple inputs.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>



int main(){

  char cmd[50];
  char cmd1[10];
  char cmd2[10];

  char str;
  int x, y, sum;


  while(1){
      scanf("%s%d%c%d", &cmd ,&x, &str, &y);

      if(strstr(cmd,"SUM")){
          sum = x + y;

          scanf("%s %s",&cmd1, &cmd2);

          if((strstr(cmd1,"DSP")) && (strstr(cmd2,"X")))
          {
               printf("%d\n",sum);
          }
          else
          {
                printf(" ");
          }

      }
    else if(strstr(cmd,"EXIT"))
        {
            break;
        }

    else
        {
            printf("INVALID INPUT!\n");
        }


      }
      return 0;
  }
```

Comment: The first `scanf` reads the string `EXIT` and then waits for you to enter a number. Try a separate `scanf` to read the `cmd`, then test if it's `EXIT` (and exit if that's the case), then `scanf` the other values.

Comment: tried it, it still waits for me to enter a number 
    scanf("%s", &input); scanf("%d%c%d",&x, &str, &y);

Comment: You need to test if `input` (in your example in the comment) is "EXIT" *before* the next scanf.

Answer (score 2):

It's because of how you use [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), it will wait for all formats to be read (or it fails).

Instead I suggest you get input using e.g. [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), then check for command, and if it's e,g. `"SUM"` *then* you parse the command arguments.